# Как отрисовать линию на матрице

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Имеется матрица 20x20. Необходимо отрисовать растровую линию от точки x1 до точки x2. С прямыми линиями вопросов нет, но вот с линиями под углом возникают проблемы.
Отрисовка самой матрицы идет через перебор элементов двумерного массива. Нужно лишь обозначить за true элементы массива, которые должны быть отрисованы иным цветом и образовывать линию.

Например: нужно обозначить элементы в массиве от [2;5] к [7;15]. Как вычислить элементы в массиве, которые нужно перевести в true, чтобы образовалась более-менее приличная линия?

Comment: Тип приложения какой? Winforms, WPF? Поставьте соответствующую метку. И вот это еще: _Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу._

Comment: @aepot Тип приложения какой? - это  неважно. С остальным  - согласен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите алгоритм [Брезенхэма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0) для рисования отрезков

Псевдокод для отрезка в первом квадранте:

```
plotLine(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    D = 2*dy - dx
    y = y0

    for x from x0 to x1
        plot(x,y)
        if D > 0
            y = y + 1
            D = D - 2*dx
        end if
        D = D + 2*dy
```